# Python dataframe, move record to another column if it contains specific value

Tags: python, dataframe

I have the following data:

For example in row 2, I want to move all the "3:xxx" to column 3, and all the "4:xxx" to column 4. How can I do that?[image: My dataset]

Btw, I have tried this but it doest work:

```
df[3] = np.where((df[2].str.contains('3:')))
```

Dataset loading:

```
url = 'https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/datasets/multiclass/iris.scale'
df = pd.read_csv(url,header=None,delim_whitespace=True)
```

Comment: How are you populating the dataframe? Is it being read from a file? And if so, can you please include a few lines from said file?

Comment: I have edited my question to include further information!

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest thing to do would be to cleanse the data set before reading it into a dataframe. In looking at the data source, it looks like there are some rows with missing fields, IE:

```
# (Missing the 3's field)
'1 1:-0.611111 2:0.166667508 4:-0.916667'
```

So I would clean up the file before reading it. For this line, you could stick an extra space between 2:0.166667508 and 4:-0.916667 to denote a null 3rd column:

```
'1 1:-0.611111 2:0.166667508 4:-0.916667 '.split(' ')
# ['1', '1:-0.611111', '2:0.166667508', '4:-0.916667', '']
'1 1:-0.611111 2:0.166667508  4:-0.916667 '.split(' ')
# ['1', '1:-0.611111', '2:0.166667508', '', '4:-0.916667', '']
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Greg's suggestion of cleansing the data set before reading it into a dataframe but still if you want to have shift on unmatched column with values then you may try this below one.

input.csv

```
1,1:-0.55,2:0.25,3:-0.86,4:-91
1,1:-0.57,2:0.26,3:-0.87,4:-0.92
1,1:-0.57,3:-0.89,4:-0.93,NaN
1,1:-0.58,2:0.25,3:-0.88,4:-0.99
```

Shift at particular index code

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('files/60009536-input.csv')
print(df)

for col_num in df.columns:
    if col_num > '0':  # Assuming there is no problem at index column 0
        for row_val in df[col_num]:
            if row_val != 'nan':
                if col_num != row_val[:1]:  # Comparing column number with sliced value
                    row = df[df[col_num] == row_val].index.values  # on true get row index as we already know column #
                    print("Found at column {0} and row {1}".format(col_num, row))
                    r_value = df.loc[row, str(row_val[:1])].values  # capturing value on target location
                    print("target location value", r_value)
                    # print("target location value", r_value[0][:1])
                    df.at[row, str(r_value[0][:1])] = r_value  # shifting target location's value to its correct loc
                    df.at[row, str(row_val[:1])] = row_val  # Shift to appropriate column
                    df.at[row, col_num] = 'NaN'  # finally update that cell to NaN

print(df)
```

output:

```
   0        1        2        3        4
0  1  1:-0.55   2:0.25  3:-0.86    4:-91
1  1  1:-0.57   2:0.26  3:-0.87  4:-0.92
2  1  1:-0.57  3:-0.89  4:-0.93      NaN
3  1  1:-0.58   2:0.25  3:-0.88  4:-0.99
Found at column 2 and row [2]
target location value ['4:-0.93']
   0        1       2        3        4
0  1  1:-0.55  2:0.25  3:-0.86    4:-91
1  1  1:-0.57  2:0.26  3:-0.87  4:-0.92
2  1  1:-0.57     NaN  3:-0.89  4:-0.93
3  1  1:-0.58  2:0.25  3:-0.88  4:-0.99

Process finished with exit code 0
```